# Creating a stack by a given array and stack C#

Tags: c#, arrays, stack

I've recently been to a job interview and have been asked this following question:

> Given an array A with N integers (different numbers between 1 and N) and a stack B with N integers (different numbers between 1 and N).
>
> The value of the item in array A contains the index in which the item is located on stack B (from the top) and the index number of array A describes the position (from the top) of stack C in which this item should appear.
>
> Write an Algorithm that runs in O(N^2) and without any further Space complexity (Besides one simple variable) that takes A and B as arguments and returns a stack C that contains N items in the order that has been described.
>
> Notice: At the end of the Algorithm, array A and stack B should be in the same form as they were when the Algorithm started.
>
> For example, given an array A that contains the following integers:

```
|     index in the array    | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 |
|:-------------------------:|---|---|---|---|
| final location in stack C | 2 | 4 | 1 | 3 |
```

> and Stack B that looks like this (But it doesn't have to look like this):

- 2
- 3
- 4
- 1

> We will return the following Stack C:

- 3
- 1
- 2
- 4

> An example:
>   in array A we are given that the item in the first index should appear on stack B at location 2 (the value 3). We will put this value in the first location (The top) of stack C.

This is my C# code that does this (Although it has several issues)

```
    private static Stack generateStackFromArrayAndStack(int[] A, Stack B)
    {
        int N = A.Length;
        Stack C = new Stack();

        // Iterate over the given array. Notice that we start from the end because that is the value we want to push first to the C Stack.
        for (int i = N - 1; i >= 0; i--)
        {
            int value = 0;
            int j;

            // Look for the desired value. When we get to it, stop this iteration. We use the Stack C as a container for now
            for (j = 1; j <= N; j++)
            {
                value = (int)B.Pop();
                C.Push(value);
                if (j == A[i])
                    break;
            }

            // Return all the items we moved to C in the previous iteration back to B.  
            for (int k = j; k > 0; k--)
                B.Push(C.Pop());

            // Push the value we want to C.
            C.Push(value);
        }
        return C;
    }
```

My issues with this code are:

1. I use more than 1 simple variable.
2. During the run of the Algorithm, stack C will contain more than N elements. Now, I'm not sure if this is allowed or not. If you can find an implementing that doesn't cause this, that would be great.

Of course if you have a completely different implementation that could also be helpful.

Comment: You would do better with codereview

Comment: Isn't codereview for peer reviews? It is a legitimate question

Answer (score 0):

No idea if this is O(N^2), but it works...

```
private static Stack<int> DoMagic(int[] a, Stack<int> b)
{
    var c = new Stack<int>();
    foreach (int val in a)
        c.Push(b.ElementAt(val-1));
    return c;
}
```

Comment: For some reason I don't have access to the method "elementAt". Any idea why?

Comment: Not using the generic version of Stack? (Stack<int>)